# Integral asymptotics

Tags: calculus, reference-request, definite-integrals, asymptotics

Is there some kind of a variation of the Laplace's method or some other formula for the asymptotics of integrals of a type
$$\int_a^bf(x)e^{mp(x)}\cos(mq(x)+x/2)dx, \ m\to\infty.$$ Here $f,p,q$ are continuous and differentiable on $[a,b]$ where $a$ and $b$ can be infinity.

I tried writing the integral as
$$\int_a^bf(x)e^{mp(x)}\mathfrak{R}e^{ix/2}e^{imq(x)}dx, \ m\to\infty,$$
but with no ideas how to proceed. Any help is very welcome.

**EDIT**: I edited the expression in $\cos$ in the original integral. I'm interested in a particular case, when $a:=0$, $b=\pi/2$, $f(x):=(\sin(x))^r\sqrt{\cos(x)},\ r>0$, $p(x):=-1/2-\sin^2(x)$, $q(x):=1/2\sin(2x)+x$.

Comment: When $r$ is not an even integer we have $$\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)e^{mp(x)}\cos(mq(x)+x/2)dx \sim \cos\left(\frac{\pi(r+1)}{2}\right) \Gamma(r+1) (2m)^{-r-1} e^{-m/2}$$ as $m \to \infty$, where $f$, $p$, and $q$ are those functions given in the edit.  When $r$ is an even integer higher-order terms must be considered.  Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to write up a complete answer but I'll try to get to it soon.

Comment: The case when $r$ is not an even integer is of much greater interest to me. But I'd like to see the even $r$ case anyway. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I was wondering, where did you come across this integral?

Comment: It shows up when analysing the Hermite coefficients $(a_m)$ of the function $|x|^r,\ r>0,$ defined as $a_m:=E |X|^rH_m(X)$, where $H_m$ is the $m$th Hermite polynomial.